# Upload image error not hide even i upload image

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I do form validation in backend in codeigniter, on clientside every field alrets work fine but on image field the error persist even i attach the image... below is my code and i am attaching image screenshort for further detail. Please help in this regards.[image]

### Here is My Controller code

```
  public function save(){
    $res = array();
    //form field validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('titlemaster', 'Main Title', 'required');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Ourpeople Main Title Required'));
        exit;
    }   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('detailmaster', 'Main Detail', 'required');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Oupeople Main Description Required'));
        exit;
    }   
    $config['upload_path'] = 'fassets/images/oupeople';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];     
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    //Load upload library and initialize configuration
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $ourpeoplesection = ($this->input->post('name')) . ($this->input->post('desig')) . ($this->input->post('aboutme')) . ($this->input->post('certification')) . ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'));
    
    if (!empty($ourpeoplesection))
    {   
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[25]');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Name Required'));
            exit;
        }           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('desig', 'Designation', 'required|max_length[20]');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Designation Required'));
            exit;
        }   
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('aboutme', 'About Employee', 'required'); 
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'About Employee Required'));
            exit;
        }       
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('certification', 'Certification', 'required');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Certification Required'));
            exit;
        }           
        
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $error = 'Please upload Image file. <br>';
            //$error = $this->upload->display_errors('', '<br>');
            echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'alert-danger', 'msg' => $error));
            exit;           
        }

        $userData = array (
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'desig' => $this->input->post('desig'),
            'aboutme' => $this->input->post('aboutme'),
            'certification' => $this->input->post('certification'),
            'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
            'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
            'instagram' => $this->input->post('instagram'),
            'google' => $this->input->post('google'),           
            'userfile' =>  $this->upload->data('file_name'),
        );
        
        //Pass user data to model
        $insertData = $this->Ourpeoplemodel->insert($userData);         
    }
    $ourpeopleMaster = array(
        'titlemaster' => $this->input->post('titlemaster') ,
        'detailmaster' => $this->input->post('detailmaster')  
    );
    $insertUserData = $this->Ourpeoplemodel->insert_main($ourpeopleMaster);  
        //Storing insertion status message.
    if(($insertUserData && $insertData)){
        $res = array(
            'mes' => 'text-success',
            'msg' => "Record has been saved successfully.",
        );
        echo json_encode($res);
    } else {
        $res = array(
            'mes' => 'text-danger',
            'msg' => "Record not saved",
        );
        echo json_encode($res);
    }      
}
```

### here my html input

```
<div class="form-group row">                                    
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <?php if(isset($ourpeople_master)){;?>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="titlemaster" value="<?php echo set_value('titlemaster', $ourpeople_master->titlemaster);?>" placeholder="Main Title | max 25 characters" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="detailmaster" value="<?php echo set_value('detailmaster', $ourpeople_master->detailmaster);?>" placeholder="Main Decription." required="required">
                </div>                  
                <?php }?> 
            </div>      
            <div class="form-group row">                                    
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">                        
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name Required">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">                    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="desig" value="" placeholder="Designation Required">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">                                                                
                    <input type="file" name="userfile" class="form-control input-sm">   
                </div>
            </div>                                  
            <div class="form-group row">                                    
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">                       
                    <textarea name='aboutme' rows="1" class='form-control input-sm'  placeholder="About Employee Detail"></textarea>                                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">                                    
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">                       
                    <textarea name='certification' rows="1" class='form-control input-sm' placeholder="Employee's Certifications Detail"></textarea>    
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group row">                                    
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook Profile Link Here">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter Profile Link Here">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram Profile Link Here">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="google" placeholder="Google Plus Profile Link Here">
                </div>
            </div>                          
            <div class="form-group row">                    
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>                                     
                </div>                                  
            </div>
```

Comment: can you put please the complete html form, not only the file input!

Comment: You're doing `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')` twice.

Comment: dear: i use only one time in validation

Comment: In line - `$ourpeoplesection = ($this->input->post('name')) ....`

Comment: i can't see the form element <form> </form> in html, edit please!

Comment: <form id="ourpeopledata" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/ourpeople/save" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>

Comment: why using $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') in $ourpeoplesection = ($this->input->post('name')) . ($this->input->post('desig')) . ($this->input->post('aboutme')) . ($this->input->post('certification')) . ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'));

Comment: To check if file is selected or not use this instead:
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) ) 
{

}

Comment: i tried this but still issue persist and if remover $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; because codeiginter by default use name for userfile as file_name so then ajax alert work and if keep this line then ajax alert not works.

Comment: `$ourpeoplesection = ($this->input->post('name')) . ($this->input->post('desig')) . ($this->input->post('aboutme')) . ($this->input->post('certification')) . ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'));` makes no sense! what are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got confused by my last answer - you can use `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` you just have to wrap it in `isset` or in this case `empty` otherwise notices will fire (and affect your json response) if the file isn't uploaded.

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'fassets/images/oupeople';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
//$config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];     
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
//Load upload library and initialize configuration
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//$ourpeoplesection = ($this->input->post('name')) . ($this->input->post('desig')) . ($this->input->post('aboutme')) . ($this->input->post('certification')) . ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'));

if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[25]');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Name Required'));
        exit;
    }           
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desig', 'Designation', 'required|max_length[20]');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Designation Required'));
        exit;
    }   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('aboutme', 'About Employee', 'required'); 
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'About Employee Required'));
        exit;
    }       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('certification', 'Certification', 'required');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => 'Certification Required'));
        exit;
    }           

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $error = 'Please upload Image file. <br>';
        //$error = $this->upload->display_errors('', '<br>');
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'alert-danger', 'msg' => $error));
        exit;           
    }

    $userData = array (
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'desig' => $this->input->post('desig'),
        'aboutme' => $this->input->post('aboutme'),
        'certification' => $this->input->post('certification'),
        'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
        'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
        'instagram' => $this->input->post('instagram'),
        'google' => $this->input->post('google'),           
        'userfile' =>  $this->upload->data('file_name'),
    );

    //Pass user data to model
    $insertData = $this->Ourpeoplemodel->insert($userData);         
}
```

I would also like to suggest instead of having many different form validation conditions just have one...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[25]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('desig', 'Designation', 'required|max_length[20]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('aboutme', 'About Employee', 'required'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('certification', 'Certification', 'required');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'text-danger', 'msg' => validation_errors()));
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You! i got it... Thanks you for you support <3